# $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ converges $\Rightarrow\sum \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum a_{n}^{2}$ converges $\Rightarrow\sum \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges.

any hints?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

detail:
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{|a_k|}k \right)^2
\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2}  \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2
\leq  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}  \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|^2
$$independant of $n$.

So the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 4):

If these are sequences of real numbers, note that, for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ 0 \leq (a-b)^2, $$
and so
$$ ab \leq \frac{1}{2}(a^2 + b^2). $$

Can you pick $a$ and $b$ so that this gives
$$ \frac{a_n}{n} \leq \text{stuff} $$
where $\sum \text{stuff}$ is a convergent series?